# RewriteCond exception only single path

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm setting up `htaccess`. How to configure it to work like this:

- `example.com/dir/*` → `example.com/dir/index.php`
- `example.com/dir/subdir/*` → `example.com/dir/index.php`
- `example.com/dir/index.html` → `example.com/dir/` (I want to replace index.php to index.html only in this directory)
- `example.com/dir/` → `example.com/dir/` (I want to see the `index.html` as content)

There are two different files in dir:

- `index.php`
- `index.html`

I am trying to ensure that these conditions work as before, with the exception of the one directory (`example.com/dir/`) only:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

That's how I tried:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php  ## trying to make index.html first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir/
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir/?$  ## trying to make an exception
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is much too complicated, unless there are additional restriction you failed to name in the question.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?dir/index\.html$ /dir/ [END]
RewriteRule ^/?dir/ /dir/index.php [END]
```

One could also understand the remark about the `index.html` file different:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?dir/(index\.php)?$ /dir/index.html [END]
RewriteRule ^/?dir/ /dir/index.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported [END] flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older [L] flag, but things get more complicated then:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?dir/(index\.php)?$ /dir/index.html [END]
RequestCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^!/dir/index\.html$
RewriteRule ^/?dir/ /dir/index.php [END]
```

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you. I edited the problem and added another condition: `example.com/dir/` → `example.com/dir/` (I want to see the index.html as content). Solution `RewriteRule ^/?dir/index\.php$ /dir/index.html [END]` didn't work for me. `RewriteRule` works fine with current conditions, but didn't work with exception with `index.html` in `/dir/`

Comment: I made a small change to variants 2 and 3 so that they now also rewrite to `index.html` for the raw directory, as requested in the last comment.